# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, when performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a button with this action:

```
@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    if(userName.text! == "staff" && password.text! == "pass") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showStaffPage", sender: self)
        } else if (userName.text! == "driver" && password.text! == "pass") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDriverPage", sender: self)
        } else if (userName.text! == "parent" && password.text! == "pass") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showParentPage", sender: self)
        } else {
            errorMsg.alpha = 1;
        }
    }
```

It works fine for "driver" and for "parent", but it gives the error below for "staff". I have tried cleaning, and I have made sure all names and locations are valid and still exist. Not sure what to try anymore.

```
2018-05-15 09:22:10.089411-0400 After School Tracker[12989:162055] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/user136086/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EE08864F-5D96-49E7-8E52-AFE0056A6BA2/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-05-15 09:22:10.089849-0400 After School Tracker[12989:162055] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-05-15 09:22:20.767770-0400 After School Tracker[12989:162055] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<After_School_Tracker.StaffViewController 0x7fd191f16d80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viewHere.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1811e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c816031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1810b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010c237b47 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d799f20 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010da87d56 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d123e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010da86700 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d7a1137 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d7a1a64 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d7a1d81 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d7a25d4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d7d3c6e -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 945
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d7ea5e2 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d7eb8cc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010da43bd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d6cd808 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b7561a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b7982b _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b0029f _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b2d940 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010d5f834f _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 167
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010df5d532 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6875
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d123bb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1084af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d107a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d10730b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112cfda73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010d5fe0b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  After School Tracker                0x000000010bef43b7 main + 55
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001115ec955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Goto your XIB, right click on file owner, check if  all the IBOutlet are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when a Storyboard Scene has a outdated `IBOutlet` to something that no longer exists. This happens to me all the time when I create an `IBOutlet`, connect it to something in Interface Builder, and then delete the associated `IBOutlet` definition in code. Unfortunately, this is only identified as a runtime issue (meaning the compiler won't catch it).

Open `StaffViewController` in Interface Builder, and open the **Connections Inspector** and look for an `IBOutlet` that is still connected, but has been deleted from the associated code file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I ended up having an extra pointer in storyboard ☹️. This helped, I wish I could up vote it but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: you can mark the answer as accepted - you should do that, and it will also grant you rep

Answer (score 0):

```
'[<After_School_Tracker.StaffViewController 0x7fd191f16d80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viewHere.
```

This means that an IBOutlet called `viewHere` is missing from your class.
if you add that, I think it will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I ended up having an extra pointer in storyboard ☹️. This helped, I wish I could up vote it but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in destination of

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showStaffPage", sender: self)
```

which is class `StaffViewController` , there is a view named `viewHere` that you removed in class code but still in IB

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I ended up having an extra pointer in storyboard ☹️. This helped, I wish I could up vote it but I don't have enough rep.